# Branding the calendar web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, branding

[image]

I would like to get rid of the pointy lines jutting out on the left of the calendar web part as shown in the red boxes in the image above. I would also like to shift the rest of the calendar to align with the left arrow on the top of the calendar. How can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS, worked for me:

```
<style>
.ms-acal-rootdiv
{
  margin-left: -8px;
}
.ms-acal-summary-dayrow > th
{
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just used table.ms-acal-month {
    margin-left: -21px;
}